# Running App from android studio on my device

Tags: android

I am having problem connecting my device(`nexus 5`) to the android studio.

Everytime I click the run button it says USB device not found even when I have connected my device to the laptop via usb and have installed the usb driver in the sdk manager.

please help

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug over USB, set up your Nexus 5 for development by enabling USB debugging on your Android device:

1. Go to **Settings > Developer options**. On Android 4.2 and newer, the developer options are hidden by default. To make it available, go to **Settings > About phone** and tap Build number seven times. Just tap it 7 times, even if it seems crazy. Then, return to the previous screen to find **Developer options**.
2. In **Developer options**, confirm that **USB debugging** is checked.

Ref: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android device, here's how you can install and run your app:

Step 1:-Plug in your device to your development machine with a USB cable. If you're developing on Windows, you might need to install the appropriate USB driver for your device. For help installing drivers, see the OEM USB Drivers document.

Step 2:-    Enable USB debugging on your device.

Note that,On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.

note :- On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options. 
Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.